# Did British Intelligence ever know about the existence of wizards and the Wizarding World?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling

I am curious to know if there was ever a time when British Intelligence (MI5) knew about the existence of wizards and the Wizarding World.

Comment: MI5 is actually the "Security Service", they would be more analogous to the FBI. And given that the British Prime Minister knows of the wizarding world, I would think at least the uppermost echelons of the security apparatus of the UK would be acquainted with the existence of wizards.

Answer (score -6):

If we take a literal reading of the Chapter Two of *Half-Blood Prince*, it would indicate that security agencies were not informed of the existence of the Wizarding community:

> The Prime Minister had stood there, quite motionless, and realized that he would never, as long as he lived, dare mention this encounter **to a living soul**, for who in the wide world would believe him?
>
> (My emphasis)

Of course it is possible for them to find out via other means, or there may be a couple of exceptions to “a living soul”.

Comment: All this says is that the PM doesn't share this info with others. The intelligence services do have other sources.

Comment: @Valorum What other sources do they have?

Comment: Observational evidence, electronic interception, witness statements, informants, etc. Your answer seems to assume that if the PM didn't tell them, that there's no other possible way for a Muggle to learn about wizards.

Comment: This also assumes that every single PM has felt the same way.

Comment: @Valorum My answer says “of course it is possible for them to find out via other means”. Without any specific evidence of the things you mention, that covers the general possibility.

Comment: "This one particular guy didn't tell them" is hardly an answer to the question.

Comment: @chepner He’s the only guy (not directly connected to wizards) that we know knows. And as prime minister he would likely know which other government officials/entities , if any, were in the loop.